# Tomcat 8 Basic auth

Tags: authentication, tomcat8

i am trying to implement BASIC auth in Apache Tomcat, but encounter a strange problem.

when i access the `http://localhost:8080.` The box is show allow to enter username and password, the problem is it seens can not auth success, the box show again and again.

below is my setting:

/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">


  <display-name>test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name></web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>my realm</realm-name>
   </login-config>


</web-app>
```

apache-tomcat-8.0.14/conf/tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
<!--   
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
-->
  <role rolename="manager" />

<!--   
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
  <user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager"/>


</tomcat-users>
```

this is my project structure

WebContent/index.jsp

just a welcome file.

what did i do wrong? or what did i miss? i have searched much for this but still can not find a solution. 
i am new to stackoverflow, hope my question is clear, and some body can help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse integrated Tomcat, then configure tomcat-users.xml file that you can see in left navigation panel of your project. Servers --> Tomcat --> tomcat-users.xml

Remove my realm from your web.xml if you have not configured a realm called 'my realm' or set my-realm value as 'default'.